# Why is Python re.sub capture not zero indexed?

Tags: python, regex

When capturing `Boiler` and `1` shown below, they are then referenced as \1 and \2. This took me a while to figure out why this was not working as I expected the capture group to be zero indexed. Why is the capture group not zero indexed unlike nearly everything in Python?

```
string = "BoilerRoom_Boiler_Booster_On"
re.sub('(Boiler)_(\d)', r'\1-\2', string)

Out[21]:
'BoilerRoom_Boiler-1_Booster_On'
```

Comment: The duplicate question didn't come up in my search as I was explicitly searching for python. I wasn't to know that it would apply to all language regex capture groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, as [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) say:

> Groups are numbered starting with 0. Group 0 is always present; it’s the whole RE

As far *why* they chose to do it like that, my guess it that Unix tools older than Python's `re` module already did it that way.

Comment: Just to clarify - the documentation is (imo) a bit unclear. Group 0 is the whole **match** of the RE, not the RE itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is zero indexed, as `group 0` represents the entire match group.